# How to free components like struct and functions in User space program?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, free

In linux kernel code i have seen so many time `__initdata` and `__init` macros to make such function and static structure as initialized time required data.

After init process Kernel it self free such memory.

So how can we implement such things in user space running c program?

See i have large  static data structure in some program and i need that in start up of some prgram after that i do not need that memory so how can i free that?

As i know static member's lifetime is until program terminates so how can program free such things?

Does this things are used in any user space c program?

Comment: What exactly is your objective? Do you want to free the memory being used by static variables or static pointers?

Comment: static variables and some gloabal variables.

Comment: Memory occupied by static variables and global variables cannot be freed, in the program's lifetime, because they are a part of the program stack.

Comment: how does that happens in kernal space..?

Comment: `__init` is a gcc macro for `__attribute__ ((__section__(".init.text")))`. If you want the same behavior as that of the kernel, you can use the `__attribute__` keyword. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__init` is a macro in `include/linux/init.h` which becomes 
`__attribute__ ((__section__(".init.text")))`

`__initdata` becomes `__attribute__ ((__section__(".init.data")))`

If you wish to simulate the behavior similar to those macros above, then you should use the `__attribute__` keyword along with the `__section__` of the binary where you want your variables to be placed.

You must know how your binary is organized, the various sections in the binary.Then refer:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes
to locate what you can do to achieve the effect you want.

Additional pointers:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Initialization.html
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134418/how-many-sections-can-i-create-in-object-file

Should help you get an idea of what `section` in executables do.

Answer (score 2):

User space runs in virtual memory so there is nothing to be gained from such methods.

Memory management will evict pages of your program when memory gets tight. They will be loaded again from disk when they are accessed. If they aren't accessed again, they won't use RAM anymore. All that happens automatically without the need for linker shenanigans.

The only reason you could want to do that anyway is if you're running out of virtual memory, which is not going to happen in 64 bit programs.